# NSManagedObject entity class method

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, ios10

I recently realized that NSManagedObject subclasses inherit a class method `entity` which can be used to obtain a `NSEntityDescription` for the class. However, I was used to having to specify a context when creating a `NSEntityDescription`, as with `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`. Is it ok to use the simpler `entity` method and what context will it be associated with ?

This method is [not really](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640588-entity?language=objc) documented by Apple.

Comment: Which language and which iOS version? (please add tags)

Comment: I don't know of a method where you can create an NSManagedObject without specifying the context. I imagine the entity is associated with whatever context the NSManagedObject was created with.

Comment: This is a class method so it is not associated to a NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSEntityDescription` is not part of a managed object context-- it's part of the managed object **model**.

When you load a data model, all of the entity descriptions it contains are loaded. The class method `+entity` works because the entity description was created along with the model object. If you try to call this method *before* loading the model, it returns `nil` in Objective-C. (In Swift for some reason it returns a non-optional value, so it's not nil, but if you use it your app will crash. Don't ask me why it's like this.)

You can also use `+entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`, as you mentioned. But look at the documentation for that method:

> Returns the entity with the specified name from the managed object model associated with the specified managed object context’s persistent store coordinator.

So even though the method takes a managed object context argument, it's still using the managed object model. It's using the context to find the model. The object that you get isn't associated with the context, it's associated with the underlying data model.

These two methods are equally safe. Use whichever works best in your code.

Comment: When you say "If you try to call this method before loading the model": when exactly is the model loaded in a typical ios usage ?

Comment: I mean, if you try to call [EntityName entity] before the `NSManagedObjectModel` that defines the entity has been loaded into memory. The method still exists but there's no entity information yet. If you use `NSPersistentContainer`, the model is loaded when you call `loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)`. If you're not using `NSPersistentContainer` then you'll have code that specifically creates an `NSManagedObjectModel` somewhere.